# How to use Multiple UIPickerViews in same View controller using UITextFields

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uipickerview

I am trying to have multiple picker views in one single view in Objective-C. So far I have created 3 different textfields and I want three of them to have different picker views if I click on them. so let us say if click on textfield #1 it opens the array #1 and textfields #2 the second  and textfields # third one. If i click the first and second text fields related picker view displaying but if i click the third one picker view is not showing.

-(void)viewDidLoad{

isBloodGroupFieldSelected = YES;

isGenderGroupFieldSelected = YES;

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

bloodGroup = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, self.view.frame.size.width-10,30)];

[self.view addSubview:bloodGroup];

txtField1 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 160, self.view.frame.size.width-10,30)];

txtField1.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:txtField1];

txtField2 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 210, self.view.frame.size.width-10,30)];

txtField2.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:txtField2];

dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A+",@"A-",@"B+",@"B-",@"O+",@"O-", nil];

genderArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Male",@"Female", nil];

ageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Age1",@"Age2", nil];

myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];

[myPickerView setDataSource: self];

[myPickerView setDelegate: self];

myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
target:self action:@selector(done:)];

UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-
myPickerView.frame.size.height-50, 320, 50)];

[toolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];

NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneButton, nil];

[toolBar setItems:toolbarItems];

bloodGroup.inputView = myPickerView;

bloodGroup.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

// txtField1

txtField1.inputView = myPickerView;

txtField1.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

txtField2.inputView = myPickerView;

txtField2.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

}

-(void)done:(id)sender{

[bloodGroup resignFirstResponder];

[txtField1 resignFirstResponder];

[txtField2 resignFirstResponder];

}

## pragma mark - UIPickerViewDataSource

// #3
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {

if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {

return 1;

}

else if(!isBloodGroupFieldSelected){

return 1;

}

else if(!isGenderGroupFieldSelected){

return 1;

}

return 0;

}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {

return [dataArray count];

}

else if(!isBloodGroupFieldSelected)

{

return [genderArray count];

}

else if(!isGenderGroupFieldSelected)

{

return [ageArray count];

}

return 0;

}

## pragma mark - UIPickerViewDelegate

// #5
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {

return dataArray[row];

}

else if(!isBloodGroupFieldSelected)

{

return genderArray[row];

}

else  if(!isGenderGroupFieldSelected)

{

return ageArray[row];

}

return 0;

}

// #6
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {

bloodGroup.text = dataArray[row];

}

else  if(!isBloodGroupFieldSelected)

{

txtField1.text = genderArray[row];

}

else if(!isGenderGroupFieldSelected)

{

txtField2.text= ageArray[row];

}

}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

if (textField == bloodGroup) {

isBloodGroupFieldSelected = YES;

}

else if (textField == txtField1){

isBloodGroupFieldSelected = NO;

isGenderGroupFieldSelected = YES;

}

else if (textField == txtField2){

isGenderGroupFieldSelected = NO;

isBloodGroupFieldSelected = NO;

}

[myPickerView reloadAllComponents];

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the problem is with your codition in titleForRow method. Once assign false to isBloodGroupFieldSelected method then pointer always move to the else part because condition is matched there before moving to the last block.

For that, you need to check both condition that

```
 (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

if (isBloodGroupFieldSelected) {

return dataArray[row];

}

else if(!isBloodGroupFieldSelected) && isGenderGroupFieldSelected

{

return genderArray[row];

}

else if(!isGenderGroupFieldSelected)

{

return ageArray[row];

}

return 0;

}
```

I suggest you to use textField tag for this. It will be easier for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer. its working good. Can you please share using Tags how can we write the code